# Haskell function nub inefficient

Tags: performance, algorithm, haskell

I'm confused by the implementation of the 'nub' (select unique values) function in the Haskell standard library *Data.List*. The GHC implementation is

```
nub l                   = nub' l []
  where
    nub' [] _           = []
    nub' (x:xs) ls
        | x `elem` ls   = nub' xs ls
        | otherwise     = x : nub' xs (x:ls)
```

As far as I can tell, this has a worst-case time complexity of O(n^2), since for a list of unique values it has to compare them all once to see that they are in fact unique.

If one used a hash table, the complexity could be reduced to O(n) for building the table + O(1) for checking each value against previous values in the hash table. Granted, this would not produce an ordered list but that would also be possible in O(n log n) using GHC's own ordered Data.Map, if that is necessary.

Why choose such an inefficient implementation for an important library function? I understand efficiency is not a main concern in Haskell but at least the standard library could make an effort to choose the (asymptotically) best data structure for the job.

Comment: Without `Ord` or `Hashable` constraints, this is the only possible implentation

Comment: By the way, using a hash table is still O(n^2) in the worst case.

Comment: @newacct Please explain your reasoning. By my count, since insertion and lookup for hash tables are O(1), we have n(O(1) + O(1)) = O(n).

Comment: @jforberg: insertion and lookup for hash tables are both O(n) in the worst case

Comment: You are right. [Don't use nub.](https://github.com/nh2/haskell-ordnub#dont-use-nub).

Comment: @newacct what if the buckets in the hash table are linked lists with simple O(1) `cons` used on collisions (and incremented count for the bucket)? wouldn't we then have O(1) insertions, always? to prevent the degeneracy (when all keys collide and we end up with unusable O(n) lookup hashtable) couldn't we re-hash with a different hash function once the degeneracy is detected (similar to the geometric expansion scheme, on doubling sizes). Wouldn't this scheme always avoid the worst case behaviour? -- I've looked into Wikipedia but didn't find any proper presentation of these issues there.

Comment: @WillNess: "what if the buckets in the hash table are linked lists with simple O(1) cons used on collisions (and incremented count for the bucket)? wouldn't we then have O(1) insertions, always?" Yes, if duplicate elements are allowed; otherwise, it would still need to iterate through the linked list to check if an equal element is already there

Comment: @WillNess: "to prevent the degeneracy (when all keys collide and we end up with unusable O(n) lookup hashtable) couldn't we re-hash with a different hash function once the degeneracy is detected (similar to the geometric expansion scheme, on doubling sizes)" The way that hash tables are implemented in most libraries, including the `hashable` package, is that the *programmer* provides the hash function for a given type, and the hash table has nothing to work with beyond that hash function, so if the programmer-provided hash function collides, there is nothing the library can do.

Comment: @WillNess: To make a nontrivial hash function for a type, you need some underlying knowledge about the type. There is no way you can generically generate a nontrivial hash function for an arbitrary unknown type. Therefore, any hash function implementation that works for arbitrary types must rely on user-provided hash functions or other user-provided information. And unless you require the user to provide a hash function that doesn't collide or have some other properties (which might not even be possible for all types), you're going to have the problem of collisions.

Comment: @newacct in this case a "user" would be a library programmer, themselves. But, collisions for non-equals would mean getting invalid results, so, would need the re-hashing done on the very first false collision, which makes it a non-deterministic algo to be run speculatively, and so destroys laziness.

Comment: @newacct (and it would still  need the `Hashable` constraint...). this also means that `cons` is replaced with storing just the first value, and doing equality check with it on subsequent collisions. --- actually, I was **wrong**: not invalid: just some values skipped falsely would appear after the re-hashing, later, out of order; so we can even have it lazy! just means we must advertise results might appear out of order. -- hmm, still makes it nondeterministic, so, *not* a function; so, **can't do it**. so, scratch all this. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Efficiency is quite a concern in Haskell, after all the language performs on par with Java, and beats it in terms of memory consumption, but of course it's not C.

The answer to your question is pretty simple: the Prelude's `nub` requires only an `Eq` constraint, while any implementation based on `Map` or `Set` would also require either an `Ord` or `Hashable`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that. But if we had function overloading or a universal hash operator, we could specify a more efficient behaviour for Hashable lists, could we not?

Comment: @jforberg If you really want to, you can achieve that with typeclasses and newtype or existential wrappers. However I'd simply prefer descriptive names like `nubOrd`, `nubHashable`.

Comment: @jforberg, how would a "universal hash operator" work exactly?

Comment: @dfeuer Java provides a hash method for all objects, typically it just returns the memory address of the object, this makes sure all Java types can be put in hashtables. I'm sure something similar could be done in Haskell, but it probably would involve contaminating the purity of the language, maybe to the point where it's not beneficial.

Comment: @jforberg, the biggest problem with that concept is that Haskell values don't have identity. They simply are not objects. Two identical pointers in the runtime system will of course always point to the same thing, but there's absolutely no guarantee that two equal things will be at the same address. For example, `let {a=[1,2];b=[1,2]} in a==b` will most certainly evaluate to True, but if you apply a mythical universal hash function, `let {a=[1,2];b=[1,2]} in uHash a == uHash b` will give a result that depends on what optimizations the compiler applies! It just doesn't work.

Comment: There is, however, a context in Haskell where there *are* "objects" with identity. Specifically, if you're working in the `ST` monad, you can compare `STRef`s for equality. I believe it would be perfectly safe to make *those* hashable; I don't know if they are.

Comment: @jforberg: "but it probably would involve contaminating the purity of the language, maybe to the point where it's not beneficial." That's absolutely correct, it would violate referential transparency. The standard prelude is completely referentially transparent, otherwise we'd have a problem if we wanted to use [Safe Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/safe-haskell.html). Also, the `base` package doesn't contain the `Hashable` typeclass. We could however have a `nubOrd` variant. I guess it just was never added without a particular reason apart from "keep it simple".

Comment: By the way: `nubOrd = map head . group . sort` is a simple, but strict implementation of `nubOrd`. A more sophisticated, lazy version would probably use `Data.Set`

Comment: @jforberg, my point was that aside from "theoretical" problems with violating referential transparency, there's an immediate practical problem because of the way Haskell is actually implemented: what you want for a hash table is a way to find a key very quickly. But a hash of the address of a copy of the key doesn't get you anything, because you may well have the wrong copy!

Comment: A simple/extreme example: hash(2*2^100::Integer) is not likely to equal hash(2^101::Integer).

Comment: @dfeuer I think [StableName](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-Mem-StableName.html) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, indeed, the caveat described on that page is the problem I mentioned. I'm frankly finding it rather difficult to come up with any situation where such a thing would be the least bit useful, the limitation being so severe.

Comment: @dfeuer E.g., it allows you to use any type as a key in [hashtables](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables). In fact, there's even [another hash table library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stable-maps), which is directly based on stable names.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, the problem is that if you insert a key into such a hash table, and then search for it, you may not find it, because you may ask for it by the wrong stable name! What use is that, exactly? In a normal hash table, yes means probably (and a definite answer will be available shortly) and no means no. In a hash table like that, yes means probably and no means ... nothing, as far as I can tell, with no apparent path to take from there.

Comment: @dfeuer You're confused. Think in pointers, not values. Two equal values are not necessarily stored in the same memory cell, and so may have different pointers, and `StableName` directly correlates to  a pointer. This is obviously a low level feature, but when used with understanding it provides one with power. It is very useful in design of mutable data-structures. If you have further questions about `StableName`, instead of prolonging this discussion please start new threads.

Comment: how come it is written in so many places that Haskell is faster than java?

Answer (score 9):

You're absolutely correct - `nub` is an O(n^2) algorithm. However, there are still reasons why you might want to use it instead of using a hashmap:

- for small lists it still might be faster
- `nub` only requires the `Eq` constraint; by comparison `Data.Map` requires an `Ord` constraint on keys and `Data.HashMap` requires a key type with both `Hashable` and `Ord` type classes
- it's lazy - you don't have to run through the entire input list to start getting results

Edit: Slight correction on the third point -- you don't have to process the entire list to start getting results; you'll still have to examine every element of the input list (so `nub` won't work on infinite lists), but you'll start returning results as soon as you find a unique element.

Comment: Agreed. But a hashtable could also be lazy since you can output unique values the first time you see them. But, well.

Answer (score 4):

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/haskell-cafe/4UJBbwVEacg/ieMzlWHUT_IJ

In my experience, "beginner" Haskell (including Prelude and the bad packages) simply ignores performance in many cases, in favor of simplicity.

Haskell performance is a complex problem to solve, so if you aren't experienced enough to search through Platform or Hackage for alternatives to the simple `nub` (and especially if your input is in a List just because you haven't thought about alternative structures), then `Data.List.nub` is likely not your only major performance problem and also you are probably writing code for a toy project where performance doesn't really matter.

You just have to have faith that when you get to building a large (in code or data) project, you will be more experienced and know how to set up your programs more efficiently.

In other words, don't worry about it, and assume that anything in Haskell 98 that comes from Prelude or base is likely to not be the most efficient way to solve a problem.