# Why does "nub" have O(n^2) complexity when it could be O(n)?

Tags: haskell

The [`nub`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:nub) function from [`Data.list`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html) has a O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity. It's clear that implementing an O(n) algorithm is doable and not hard. Why doesn't Haskell do it?

```
nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
base Data.List
O(n^2). The nub function removes duplicate elements from a list. In particular,
it keeps only the first occurrence of each element. (The name nub means
`essence'.) It is a special case of nubBy, which allows the programmer to supply
their own equality test.
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to implement an O(n) nub algorithm for the type `Eq a => [a] -> [a]`. It *would* be possible for `Ord a => [a] -> [a]`. I don't know why they wanted to use the former type though. I *think* that decision was controversial but it's been a while since I've heard it discussed.

Comment: As has been mentioned, `nub` needs to operate on `Eq`s, and there are plenty of other structures available that are more efficient. Have any other examples?

Comment: at most....after sorting the list (eq does not mean it's sortable), you could get n*O(n), but you'd lose the element order in the process... Keeping the order means comparing each element with every other one -> O(n^2)

Comment: omu_negru: it is possible to keep the original index of an element in a separate data structure and to switch them back afterwards. The overhead is still linear so irrelevant in a O(nlogn) algorithm. That means with a `Ord` instead of an `Eq` constraint we could indeed do better.

Comment: Saying that implementing an O(n) function isn't hard is not enough.  You have to show us how. :)

Comment: I would have thought that you would have attempted to implement it in `O(n)` before stating something like this.

Comment: @DavidYoung: How would you do it for `Ord a => [a] -> [a]`?

Comment: @newacct Oh, I was thinking of O(nlogn)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell function nub inefficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209798/haskell-function-nub-inefficient)

Answer (score 35):

To provide the answer that has been made rather painfully explicit in the comments: Your premise is wrong, `nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]` can not have an `O(n)` implementation.

You are probably thinking of an implementation that can assume ordering, `ordNub :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]`, this is usually linear log.  That or perhaps you are assuming a hashable, bucket-sortable sort of thing.  Unlike with `Eq`, when you have ordering information you don't need to potentially compare every pair of elements.

This topic was discussed in 2008: http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/GHC-2717-Add-nubWith-nubOrd-td3159919.html

This topic was discussed again, with almost completely different actors in the community, in 2013: https://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-October/110984.html